# Jquery current page link styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to make the link of the current page the user is on styled differently to the other links in the navigation bar.

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(function() {
                $('.Global_Nav li').each(function() {
                    var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
                    if ($(this).attr('href')  ===  window.location.pathname) {
                        $(this).addClass('current');
                    }
                });
            }); 
        })
    </script>
```

This is the jquery i've found which seems to be the code that makes the most sense for what i'm trying to achieve.

```
.Global_Nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    height: 35px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    list-style: none;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    
    
}

.Global_Nav li.current{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    height: 35px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    list-style: none;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #B8B8C7;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The CSS above is what the links should be styled like beforehand and when it's the current page. Below is the HTML of the Navigation bar.

```
<nav class="Global_Nav">
            <ul id="Global_links">
                <li><a href="HomeTemplate.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="NewsTemplate.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="MultimediaTemplate.html">Multimedia</a></li>
                <li><a href="SocialTemplate.html">Social</a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sorry if it's a duplicate I did have a look around beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

use location.href.

This post url using window.location.pathname : "/questions/28988304/jquery-current-page-link-styling"

This post url using location.href : "[Jquery current page link styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988304/jquery-current-page-link-styling)"

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href` instead of `window.location.pathname`:

```
if ( $(this).attr('href') == window.location.href ) {       
    $(this).addClass('current');
}
```